# angular 2 when call onout focous in currency field

Tags: angular2-forms

when we like below mentioned:
 [ngModel]="RcpAmnt |  currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'" in angular 2 kendo textbox then give the on out focous it give error how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spinners]="false"  [(ngModel)] ="value">